# Exception errors on Magento 2 website

Tags: magento, magento2

I have a Magento website and whenever I click on a product this Exception error comes up. I cannot understand though where this error comes from. I tried give some extra permissions to some files regarding some similar posts I found here but none of them worked.

This is what comes up

```
    1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method MageArray\HidePrice\Block\Options::decorateArray

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method MageArray\HidePrice\Block\Options::decorateArray
#0 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options.phtml(12): Magento\Framework\DataObject->__call('decorateArray', Array)
#1 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options.phtml(12): MageArray\HidePrice\Block\Options->decorateArray(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/html/f...')
#3 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(MageArray\HidePrice\Block\Options), '/var/www/html/f...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/f...')
#5 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/app/code/MageArray/HidePrice/Block/Options.php(31): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#6 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(659): MageArray\HidePrice\Block\Options->_toHtml()
#7 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#8 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('product.info.op...')
#9 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('product.info.op...')
#10 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('product.info.op...')
#11 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('product.info.op...', true)
#12 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(503): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('product.info.op...', true)
#13 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Interceptor.php(778): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('', true)
#14 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml(15): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor->getChildHtml('', true)
#15 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/html/f...')
#16 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor), '/var/www/html/f...', Array)
#17 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Interceptor.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/f...')
#18 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor->fetchView('/var/www/html/f...')
#19 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(659): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#20 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Interceptor.php(869): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#21 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor->toHtml()
#22 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('product.info.op...')
#23 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('product.info.op...')
#24 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('product.info.op...')
#25 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('product.info.op...', true)
#26 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('product.info.op...', true)
#27 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Interceptor.php(791): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildChildHtml('options_contain...', '', true)
#28 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml(35): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor->getChildChildHtml('options_contain...')
#29 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/html/f...')
#30 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor), '/var/www/html/f...', Array)
#31 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Interceptor.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/f...')
#32 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor->fetchView('/var/www/html/f...')
#33 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(659): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#34 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Interceptor.php(869): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#35 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor->toHtml()
#36 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('product.info')
#37 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('product.info')
#38 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('product.info')
#39 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('product.info', true)
#40 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('product.info')
#41 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('product.info.ma...')
#42 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('product.info.ma...')
#43 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('product.info.ma...')
#44 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('product.info.ma...', true)
#45 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('product.info.ma...')
#46 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.product.co...')
#47 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.product.co...')
#48 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.product.co...')
#49 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.product.co...', true)
#50 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.product.co...')
#51 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.product.co...')
#52 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.product.co...')
#53 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.product.co...')
#54 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.product.co...', true)
#55 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.product.co...')
#56 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content')
#57 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#58 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#59 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', true)
#60 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content')
#61 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main')
#62 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#63 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#64 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', true)
#65 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main')
#66 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.columns.gr...')
#67 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.columns.gr...')
#68 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.columns.gr...')
#69 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.columns.gr...', true)
#70 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.columns.gr...')
#71 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.columns.gr...')
#72 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.columns.gr...')
#73 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.columns.gr...')
#74 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.columns.gr...', true)
#75 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.columns.gr...')
#76 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns')
#77 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#78 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#79 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', true)
#80 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns')
#81 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content')
#82 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#83 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#84 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', true)
#85 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content')
#86 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#87 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#88 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#89 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', true)
#90 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#91 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#92 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#93 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#94 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#95 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(938): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#96 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#97 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#98 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(243): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#99 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#100 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#101 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#102 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-builtin-...')
#103 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(67): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#104 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#105 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-varnish-...')
#106 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/VarnishPlugin.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#107 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#108 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#109 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#110 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#111 /var/www/html/website.com/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#112 {main}
```

Comment: I suggest you contact "MageArray" and ask them for support for their module

Answer (score 0):

Check the function decorateArray() inside the class MageArray\HidePrice\Block\Options if exists. This class must extends the Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options class where the default decorateArray() functions is declared.